# Dynamic GridView generation

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic, web-controls

I may be out of my league here with this, but for the past couple of days I've tried designing the ultimate dynamic gridview generation mechanism .. then I got stuck. :)

So, why ultimate?

Well, I have 2 tables where I map every list-like (nomenclatures) tables in an app (eg: person types, address types, client types, counties, countries, etc).

Instead of creating a gridview for each and one of these tables, I want to create a mechanism that will generate each of these tables dynamically into a gridview with all CRUD functionalities included. This means that I will need both the EditItemTemplate and FooterTemplate to work.

Here goes:
Underlying "config" tables for this mechanism:

```
CREATE TABLE EXP_LIST_COLUMN_TYPE
(
COLUMN_TYPE_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT IDX_PK_COLUMN_TYPE_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
COLUMN_TYPE NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE EXP_LIST_HEADER
(
LIST_HEADER_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT IDX_PK_LIST_HEADER_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
DISPLAY_NAME NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
ACTIVE INT NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE EXP_LIST_DETAILS
(
LIST_DETAIL_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT IDX_PK_LIST_DETAIL_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
LIST_HEADER_ID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_LIST_HEADER_ID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EXP_LIST_HEADER(LIST_HEADER_ID),
DISPLAY_COLUMN_NAME NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
DISPLAY_COLUMN_TYPE_ID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_COL_TYPE_ID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EXP_LIST_COLUMN_TYPE(COLUMN_TYPE_ID),
DISPLAY_COLUMN_LENGTH INT NOT NULL,
VISIBLE INT NOT NULL,
DDL_LIST_DETAIL_ID INT NULL CONSTRAINT DDL_LIST_DETAIL_ID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EXP_LIST_DETAILS(LIST_DETAIL_ID),
COLUMN_NAME NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
GO


INSERT INTO EXP_LIST_COLUMN_TYPE
(COLUMN_TYPE)
SELECT 'Date'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TextBox'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Label'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'CheckBox'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DropDownList'
GO

INSERT INTO EXP_LIST_HEADER
(DISPLAY_NAME,TABLE_NAME,TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY,ACTIVE)
SELECT 'Person Types','PERSON_TYPE','PERSON_TYPE_ID',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Address Types','ADDRESS_TYPES','ADDRESS_TYPE_ID',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Countries','COUNTRY','COUNTRY_ID',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Counties','COUNTY','COUNTY_ID',1
GO

INSERT INTO EXP_LIST_DETAILS
(
LIST_HEADER_ID,
DISPLAY_COLUMN_NAME,
DISPLAY_COLUMN_TYPE_ID,
DISPLAY_COLUMN_LENGTH,
VISIBLE,
DDL_LIST_DETAIL_ID,
COLUMN_NAME
)
SELECT 1,'Person Type',2,255,1,NULL,'TYPENAME'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Address Type',2,255,1,NULL,'ADDRESS_TYPE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Country Code',2,3,1,NULL,'CODE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Country Name',2,255,1,NULL,'NAME'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'County Code',2,3,1,NULL,'CODE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'County Name',2,255,1,NULL,'NAME'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'Country',5,3,1,3,'COUNTRY_ID'
GO
```

And 2 stored procedures that will output the header and the details, something like this:

```
--GET LIST HEADER
IF OBJECT_ID(N'USP_GET_LIST_HEADER','P') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE USP_GET_LIST_HEADER 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE USP_GET_LIST_HEADER @LIST_HEADER_ID INT
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT DISTINCT
      H.LIST_HEADER_ID
    , H.DISPLAY_NAME
    , H.TABLE_NAME
    , H.TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY
    FROM EXP_LIST_HEADER H
    JOIN EXP_LIST_DETAILS D ON D.LIST_HEADER_ID = H.LIST_HEADER_ID
    WHERE
        H.LIST_HEADER_ID = @LIST_HEADER_ID
    AND H.ACTIVE = 1        
END
GO

--GET LIST DETAILS
IF OBJECT_ID(N'USP_GET_LIST_DETAILS','P') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE USP_GET_LIST_DETAILS 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE USP_GET_LIST_DETAILS @LIST_HEADER_ID INT
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT
      D.LIST_DETAIL_ID
    , D.DISPLAY_COLUMN_NAME
    , D.VISIBLE
    , CT.COLUMN_TYPE
    , D.DISPLAY_COLUMN_LENGTH
    , DDLH.TABLE_NAME + '.' + DDLH.TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY AS DDL_VALUE
    , DDLH.TABLE_NAME + '.' + DDLD.COLUMN_NAME AS DDL_TEXT
    , DDLH.TABLE_NAME AS DDL_TABLE
    , D.COLUMN_NAME      
    FROM EXP_LIST_HEADER H
    JOIN EXP_LIST_DETAILS D ON D.LIST_HEADER_ID = H.LIST_HEADER_ID
    JOIN EXP_LIST_COLUMN_TYPE CT ON CT.COLUMN_TYPE_ID = D.DISPLAY_COLUMN_TYPE_ID
    LEFT JOIN EXP_LIST_DETAILS DDLD ON DDLD.LIST_DETAIL_ID = D.DDL_LIST_DETAIL_ID
    LEFT JOIN EXP_LIST_HEADER DDLH ON DDLH.LIST_HEADER_ID = DDLD.LIST_HEADER_ID
    WHERE
        H.LIST_HEADER_ID = @LIST_HEADER_ID
    AND H.ACTIVE = 1        
END
GO
```

These 2 sp will give me the structure of the gridview as such:

```
EXEC USP_GET_LIST_HEADER 4
```

[image]

```
EXEC USP_GET_LIST_DETAILS 4
```

[image]

Given that, I have a web form in which I have a dropdownlist from where the user selects the list he would like to manage and based on the user's selection, a gridview will dynamically get generated based on the underlying data:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLists" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsLists"
DataTextField="LIST_NAME" DataValueField="LIST_HEADER_ID" Width="100%" 
Font-Bold="true" AutoPostBack="true" 
onselectedindexchanged="ddlLists_SelectedIndexChanged" >
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="updpgrDynamicList" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updpanDynamicList">
    <ProgressTemplate> 
        <img src="../Images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Please wait..." /> 
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updpanDynamicList" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate> 

    <asp:GridView ID="gvDynamicList" runat="server"
    Visible="true" ShowFooter="true"
    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages" 
    PagerStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" PagerStyle-NextPageText="Next" PagerStyle-PrevPageText="Prev" 
    BorderWidth="0" GridLines="Both" CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="0" 
    Font-Name="Verdana" Font-Size="7pt" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
    HeaderStyle-BackColor="#aaaadd" AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="#eeeeee"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    onpageindexchanging="gvDynamicList_PageIndexChanging" 
    onrowcancelingedit="gvDynamicList_RowCancelingEdit" 
    onrowcommand="gvDynamicList_RowCommand" 
    onrowdeleting="gvDynamicList_RowDeleting" 
    onrowediting="gvDynamicList_RowEditing" 
    onrowupdating="gvDynamicList_RowUpdating" 
    >
    <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="Red" Font-Bold="true"/>                
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#ececff" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#30308f" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="7pt" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>

    <Columns>
              
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<br /> 

<asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsLists" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LocalSqlServer %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT LIST_HEADER_ID, DISPLAY_NAME AS LIST_NAME FROM EXP_LIST_HEADER WHERE ACTIVE=1 UNION ALL SELECT -1,'' ORDER BY 1 ASC">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The codebehind:

```
protected void ddlLists_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ListHeaderId;
        Int32.TryParse(ddlLists.SelectedItem.Value.ToString(), out ListHeaderId);

        if (ListHeaderId != 0)
        {
            try
            {
                PopulateDynamicGridView(ListHeaderId);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblError.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void PopulateDynamicGridView(int ListHeaderId)
    {
        gvDynamicList.Columns.Clear();
        gvDynamicList.DataBind();
        
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlGetListHeader = new SqlCommand(@"EXEC USP_GET_LIST_HEADER @LIST_HEADER_ID", sqlConn);

            sqlGetListHeader.Parameters.Add("@LIST_HEADER_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            sqlGetListHeader.Parameters["@LIST_HEADER_ID"].Value = ListHeaderId;

            SqlDataAdapter daListHeader = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlGetListHeader);
            DataTable dtListHeader = new DataTable("LIST_HEADER");

            SqlCommand sqlGetListDetails = new SqlCommand(@"EXEC USP_GET_LIST_DETAILS @LIST_HEADER_ID", sqlConn);

            sqlGetListDetails.Parameters.Add("@LIST_HEADER_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            sqlGetListDetails.Parameters["@LIST_HEADER_ID"].Value = ListHeaderId;

            SqlDataAdapter daListDetails = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlGetListDetails);
            DataTable dtListDetails = new DataTable("LIST_DETAILS");

            try
            {
                sqlConn.Open();

                daListHeader.Fill(dtListHeader);

                if (dtListHeader.Rows.Count == 1)
                {
                    daListDetails.Fill(dtListDetails);

                    if (dtListDetails.Rows.Count >= 1)
                    {
                        string sqlDynamicCommand = "SELECT " + dtListHeader.Rows[0]["TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY"].ToString() + ", ";
                        
                        //add the primary key of the underlying table as a bound field to the gv 
                        //useful later in edit mode
                        BoundField bfGVPk = new BoundField();

                        bfGVPk.DataField = dtListHeader.Rows[0]["TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY"].ToString();
                        bfGVPk.ReadOnly = true;
                        bfGVPk.HeaderText = dtListHeader.Rows[0]["TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY"].ToString();
                        bfGVPk.Visible = false;

                        gvDynamicList.Columns.Add(bfGVPk);

                        foreach(DataRow drDetails in dtListDetails.Rows)
                        {
                            string DisplayColumnName = drDetails["DISPLAY_COLUMN_NAME"].ToString();
                            int Visible =  Convert.ToInt32(drDetails["VISIBLE"].ToString());
                            string ColumnType = drDetails["COLUMN_TYPE"].ToString();
                            int ColumnLength = Convert.ToInt32(drDetails["DISPLAY_COLUMN_LENGTH"].ToString());
                            string DDLValue = drDetails["DDL_VALUE"].ToString();
                            string DDLText = drDetails["DDL_TEXT"].ToString();
                            string DDLTable = drDetails["DDL_TABLE"].ToString();
                            string ColumnName = drDetails["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString();

                            if (ColumnType != "DropDownList")
                            {
                                TemplateField tmplfield = new TemplateField();

                                tmplfield.HeaderTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Header, DisplayColumnName, Visible);
                                tmplfield.ItemTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Item, ColumnName,"Label");
                                tmplfield.EditItemTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.EditItem, DisplayColumnName, ColumnName, ColumnType, Visible, ColumnLength);
                                tmplfield.FooterTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Footer, DisplayColumnName, ColumnName, ColumnType, Visible, ColumnLength); 

                                gvDynamicList.Columns.Add(tmplfield);                                
                            }

                            sqlDynamicCommand += ColumnName + ",";

                        }

                        //add the edit column 
                        TemplateField tmplfieldEdit = new TemplateField();

                        tmplfieldEdit.HeaderTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Header, "Edit", 1);
                        tmplfieldEdit.ItemTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Item, "Edit", "ImageButton");
                        tmplfieldEdit.EditItemTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.EditItem, "", "", "ImageButton", 1, 0);
                        tmplfieldEdit.FooterTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Footer, "", "", "ImageButton", 1, 0);
                        gvDynamicList.Columns.Add(tmplfieldEdit);   

                        //add the delete column
                        TemplateField tmplfieldDelete = new TemplateField();

                        tmplfieldDelete.HeaderTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Header, "Delete", 1);
                        tmplfieldDelete.ItemTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Item, "Delete", "ImageButton");
                        gvDynamicList.Columns.Add(tmplfieldDelete);

                        //removing the final comma
                        sqlDynamicCommand = sqlDynamicCommand.Substring(0, sqlDynamicCommand.Length - 1);
                        //adding the table
                        sqlDynamicCommand += " FROM " + dtListHeader.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                        using (SqlConnection sqlConnDynamicDS = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString))
                        {
                            SqlCommand sqlGetDynamicDataSource = new SqlCommand(sqlDynamicCommand, sqlConnDynamicDS);

                            SqlDataAdapter daDynamic = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlGetDynamicDataSource);
                            DataTable dtDynamic = new DataTable("DYNAMIC_DATA_SOURCE");

                            daDynamic.Fill(dtDynamic);

                            gvDynamicList.DataSource = dtDynamic;
                            gvDynamicList.DataBind();
                        }
                    }                   
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

And my implementation of the ITemplate:

```
public class GridViewTemplate : System.Web.UI.Page, ITemplate 
{

    ListItemType _templateType;
    string _columnName;
    string _controlType;
    int _visible;
    int _columnLength;
    string _displayColumnName;

    //Header constructor
    public GridViewTemplate(ListItemType type, string displaycolumnname,int visible)
    {
        _templateType = type;
        _displayColumnName = displaycolumnname;
        _visible = visible;
    }

    //Item constructor
    public GridViewTemplate(ListItemType type, string columnname, string controlType)
    {
        _templateType = type;
        _columnName = columnname;
        _controlType = controlType;
    }

    //EditItem and Footer constructor
    public GridViewTemplate(ListItemType type,string displaycolumnname, string colname, string controltype, int visible, int columnlength)
    {
        _templateType = type;
        _columnName = colname;
        _controlType = controltype;
        _visible = visible;
        _columnLength = columnlength;
        _displayColumnName = displaycolumnname;
    }

    void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        switch (_templateType)
        {
            
            case ListItemType.Header:
                try
                {
                    //Headers will always be labels
                    Label lblHeader = new Label();
                    lblHeader.Text = _displayColumnName;
                    if (_visible != 1)
                    {
                        lblHeader.Visible = false;
                    }
                    container.Controls.Add(lblHeader);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                break;

            case ListItemType.Item:
                try
                {
                    //Items can be only Labels or ImageButtons
                    if (_controlType == "Label")
                    {
                        Label lblItem = new Label();
                        lblItem.ID = "lbl" + _columnName;
                        lblItem.Text = String.Empty;

                        lblItem.DataBinding += new EventHandler(OnDataBinding);
                        container.Controls.Add(lblItem);
                    }

                    if (_controlType == "ImageButton" && _columnName == "Edit")
                    {
                        ImageButton imgbtnItem = new ImageButton();
                        imgbtnItem.ID = "img_btnEdit";
                        imgbtnItem.CommandName = "Edit";
                        imgbtnItem.ImageUrl = "~/Images/document_edit.png";
                        imgbtnItem.AlternateText = _columnName;
                        imgbtnItem.CausesValidation = false;
                        imgbtnItem.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imgbtnItem_Edit);

                        container.Controls.Add(imgbtnItem);                       
                    }

                    if (_controlType == "ImageButton" && _columnName == "Delete")
                    {
                        ImageButton imgbtnItem = new ImageButton();
                        imgbtnItem.ID = "btnDelete";
                        imgbtnItem.CommandName = "Delete";
                        imgbtnItem.ImageUrl = "~/Images/document_delete.png";
                        imgbtnItem.AlternateText = _columnName;
                        imgbtnItem.CausesValidation = false;
                        imgbtnItem.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')";

                        container.Controls.Add(imgbtnItem);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                break;

            case ListItemType.EditItem:
                try
                {
                    if (_controlType == "TextBox")
                    {
                        TextBox tbEditItem = new TextBox();
                        tbEditItem.ID = "tbEdit" + _columnName;
                        tbEditItem.Text = String.Empty;
                        tbEditItem.DataBinding += new EventHandler(OnDataBinding);
                        tbEditItem.MaxLength = _columnLength;
                    }

                    if (_controlType == "Label")
                    {
                        //Labels will basically render the control in a ReadOnly state
                        Label lblEditItem = new Label();
                        lblEditItem.ID = "lblEditItem" + _columnName;
                        lblEditItem.Text = String.Empty;
                        lblEditItem.DataBinding += new EventHandler(OnDataBinding);
                    }

                    if (_controlType == "Date")
                    {
                        TextBox tbDateEditItem = new TextBox();
                        tbDateEditItem.ID = "tbDateEdit" + _columnName;
                        tbDateEditItem.Text = String.Empty;
                        tbDateEditItem.MaxLength = _columnLength;
                        tbDateEditItem.DataBinding += new EventHandler(OnDataBinding);

                        AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender ajCe = new AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender();
                        ajCe.ID = "ceEdit" + _columnName;
                        ajCe.Format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
                        ajCe.TargetControlID = tbDateEditItem.ID;
                    }
                    if (_controlType == "DropDownList")
                    {
                        //work in progress :)
                    }

                    //Here we will add 2 ImageButtons inside the EditItemTemplate
                    //One will be to Save the edited date
                    //The other one will close the edit mode of the gridview (Cancel)
                    if (_controlType == "ImageButton")
                    {
                        ImageButton imgbtnEditItemSave = new ImageButton();
                        imgbtnEditItemSave.ID = "img_btnSave";
                        imgbtnEditItemSave.CommandName = "Update";
                        imgbtnEditItemSave.ImageUrl = "~/Images/document_save.png";
                        imgbtnEditItemSave.AlternateText = "Save";
                        imgbtnEditItemSave.CausesValidation = true;
                        imgbtnEditItemSave.ValidationGroup = "SaveRow";  //in case a validation is defined on any other EditItems

                        ImageButton imgbtnEditItemEditClose = new ImageButton();
                        imgbtnEditItemEditClose.ID = "img_btnCancel";
                        imgbtnEditItemEditClose.CommandName = "Cancel";
                        imgbtnEditItemEditClose.ImageUrl = "~/Images/document_cancel.png";
                        imgbtnEditItemEditClose.AlternateText = "Cancel";
                        imgbtnEditItemEditClose.CausesValidation = false;                        
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                break;

            case ListItemType.Footer:

                if (_controlType == "TextBox")
                {
                    TextBox tbNewItem = new TextBox();
                    tbNewItem.ID = "tbNew" + _columnName;
                    tbNewItem.Text = String.Empty;
                    tbNewItem.MaxLength = _columnLength;
                }

                if (_controlType == "ImageButton")
                {
                    ImageButton imgbtnAddNewItem = new ImageButton();
                    imgbtnAddNewItem.ID = "img_btnInsert";
                    imgbtnAddNewItem.CommandName = "AddNew";
                    imgbtnAddNewItem.ImageUrl = "~/Images/document_insert.png";
                    imgbtnAddNewItem.AlternateText = "Insert";
                    imgbtnAddNewItem.CausesValidation = true;
                    imgbtnAddNewItem.ValidationGroup = "AddRow";
                }
                if (_controlType == "DropDownList")
                {
                    //work in progress :)
                }

                if (_controlType == "CheckBox")
                {
                    //work in progress :)
                }

                if (_controlType == "Date")
                {
                    TextBox tbNewItem = new TextBox();
                    tbNewItem.ID = "tbNew" + _columnName;
                    tbNewItem.Text = String.Empty;
                    tbNewItem.MaxLength = _columnLength;

                    AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender ajCe = new AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender();
                    ajCe.ID = "ceEdit" + _columnName;
                    ajCe.Format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
                    ajCe.TargetControlID = tbNewItem.ID;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void imgbtnItem_Edit(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void OnDataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        object bound_value_obj = null;
        Control ctrl = (Control)sender;
        IDataItemContainer data_item_container = (IDataItemContainer)ctrl.NamingContainer;
        bound_value_obj = DataBinder.Eval(data_item_container.DataItem, _columnName);

        switch (_templateType)
        {
            case ListItemType.Item:
                Label field_ltrl = (Label)sender;
                field_ltrl.Text = bound_value_obj.ToString();
                break;

            case ListItemType.EditItem:
                TextBox field_txtbox = (TextBox)sender;
                field_txtbox.Text = bound_value_obj.ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the form, the Header and Item templates seems more than ok, BUT I have nothing in the footer. I should have had 2 textboxes and an `ImageButton` here, but I don't:
[image]

Also, when I press the Edit image button, of any of the rows, this is what I get:
[image]

From what I've noticed, in Edit mode it never fires the `OnDataBinding` event when the `ListItemType` is `EditItem`.

I know there's a lot of code to digest here, but if I can get this to work I will post the entire code so that everyone out there can benefit from it if they'll find it interesting.

Any ideas would be more than welcomed!!

Comment: After setting your datasource you should call DataBind();

Comment: @FeliceM I am, please check the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Look For `Edit Index` And find Edit Button Click in `RowCommand` i hope it will help you.

Comment: The gridview enters in the Edit mode, it's just that it won't fire the DataBinding() event and somehow it's not displaying any of my EditItem controls. Also when it loads, it won't display the footer items either. I'm starting to believe that it is impossible to achieve this...

Comment: That's when it will exit the edit mode, but my problem comes when I am entering the edit mode + the fact that footer row is not displayed ... Please see the images I've uploaded.